# How to deal with async data, React Context and hooks

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, react-hooks, apollo-client, react-context

On App load, I am fetching the user profile (with Apollo query hook) that I store in the Context.

```js
const AuthContext = createContext()

export const AuthProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const user = useQuery(GET_PROFILE)
  
  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={user}>
      {children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  )
}

export const useAuth = () => {
  return useContext(AuthContext)
}
```

Then I have a custom hook that will call the context to retrieve user information. I am using the result right away as a query parameter (the query is executed as soon as the hook is called)

```js
export const useProject = () => {
  const user = useAuth()

  console.log('Current project ID', user?.currentProjectId) // undefined

  const data = useQuery(
    GET_PROJECT, {
      variables: {
        projectId: user?.currentProjectId // Error: Variable "$projectId" of required type "ID!" was not provided.
      }
    }
  )

  return data
}
```

The problem is `user` is used as before the data is available.

If the data was used in a presentational component, I would use a Loader or Suspense but how can I make it work inside a hook? How can I make sure the query is executed with the `user` data available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [skip](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/queries/#skip) parameter to disable the query when a certain condition is not met. In this case, if the user variable is not defined.

```
export const useProject = () => {
  const user = useAuth()

  const data = useQuery(
    GET_PROJECT, {
      skip: !user,
      variables: {
        projectId: user?.currentProjectId // Error: Variable "$projectId" of required type "ID!" was not provided.
      }
    }
  )

  return data
}
```